# Cartopy cannot show latitude labels in projection of EckertIII

Tags: matplotlib, plot, cartopy

Cartopy is not showing latitude labels in a simple plot.
What can be set to show the latitude labels?
The codes will create the figure, but the lat labels not shown.
If change the projection to PlateCarree, then there is no problem to show labels.

[image]

The python code is:

```python
# Setup a global EckertIII map with faint coastlines.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1, projection=ccrs.EckertIII())
# ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
x = np.arange(-90, 90)
y = x.copy()
x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x2*y2
filled_c = ax.contourf(x2, y2, z, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
line_c = ax.contour(x2, y2, z, levels=filled_c.levels,
                    colors=['black'],
                    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.colorbar(filled_c, orientation='vertical', ax=ax)
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines('110m', alpha=0.1)
# Use the line contours to place contour labels.
ax.clabel(
    line_c,  # Typically best results when labelling line contours.
    colors=['black'],
    manual=False,  # Automatic placement vs manual placement.
    inline=True,  # Cut the line where the label will be placed.
    fmt=' {:.0f} '.format,  # Labes as integers, with some extra space.
)
# # s0
# ax.gridlines(color='k', linestyle='--', draw_labels=True)

# # s1
gl = ax.gridlines(
    xlocs=[-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180],
    ylocs=[-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90],
    draw_labels=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False,
    lw=0.5, linestyle='--', color='gray'
)
# gl.top_labels = False
# gl.right_labels = True
gl.rotate_labels = False
```

Comment: I figured out myself that, it is caused by the property of class gridlines.rotate_labels. It is set to True by default, and while plotting it with EckertIII, only latitude labels are shown, because they are rotated. If I set rotate label to False, then it only shows non-rotated labels, except latitude labels outside of 0 degree. I use cartopy 0.18, so not sure if it is fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself, by running gridlines for the figure twice.
First run is set rotate labels True, and 2nd run is set this False.
Then the gridlines will be drawn for them.

```
 # 1st to draw the rotate labels
    gl = ax.gridlines(color='k', linestyle='--', lw=0.5, draw_labels=True)
  
    # 2nd to draw the non-rotate labels
    gl = ax.gridlines(color='k', linestyle='--', lw=0.5, draw_labels=True)
  
    gl.rotate_labels = False
```